# PHP Dividing 3 digit Number by onedigit

Tags: php

I created this php file and output was weird. Anyone Reason why this kind of thing happen in php?

```
<?php

  $i=014;
  echo $i/2;

?>
```

The output is 6.

Is this happen because of number bases or anything?

Comment: If a number starts with a leading zero that means it is a octal digit. So this is 14 base 8. When you divide 14 base 8 by 2 result is 6. Remove leading zero and you will get 14 base 10 number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number start with 0 is treated as octal number in PHP. Here `014` is octal number and equivalent to `12` in decimal number system. That's why it is showing `6`  as output.

[octdec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.octdec.php) function to convert octal to decimal.